# Why isn't python package in my environment, even though "poetry add <package>" succeeded and the virtual env is activated?

Tags: pip, virtualenv, python-poetry

Using `poetry`, I init'ed a new project, created a new env, and added a package, but the package is not showing up with `pip3` -- why not?

e.g., when I run the following commands:

```shell
set -x
rm -fr /tmp/my-project
mkdir /tmp/my-project
cd /tmp/my-project
poetry init --no-interaction --python=3.7.13
pyenv local 3.7.13
poetry env use python
poetry env list  # confirm virtual env is activated
echo 'Note that the virtual env is "(Activated)" above.'
poetry add chardet
poetry show
pip3 list  # no chardet -- why not?
echo 'Why is chardet not present above?'
```

I get the following output:

```shell
+ rm -fr /tmp/my-project
+ mkdir /tmp/my-project
+ cd /tmp/my-project
+ poetry init --no-interaction --python=3.7.13
+ pyenv local 3.7.13
+ poetry env use python
Using virtualenv: /Users/robbednark/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-project-QXbwbAtx-py3.7
+ poetry env list
my-project-QXbwbAtx-py3.7 (Activated)
+ echo 'Note that the virtual env is "(Activated)" above.'
Note that the virtual env is "(Activated)" above.
+ poetry add chardet
Using version ^5.2.0 for chardet

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.1s)

No dependencies to install or update

Writing lock file
+ poetry show
chardet 5.2.0 Universal encoding detector for Python 3
+ pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.3.2
setuptools 47.1.0
+ echo 'Why is chardet not present above?'
Why is chardet not present above?
```

Answer (score 0):

The virtual env needs to be activated using either `poetry shell`, `poetry run <cmd>`, or sourcing the virtualenv,  e.g.,

```shell
$ poetry shell
$ pip3 list
```

or this:

```shell
$ poetry run -- pip3 list
```

or this:

```shell
$ source "$(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate"
$ pip3 list
```

I don't know why `poetry env list` shows the environment as activated before run any of these are run.